# Help with indexing narrow table with many millions of rows

Tags: sql-server, index, performance, query-performance

I have a good amount of experience with SQL Server, but not much with indexes and I fear I'm a little bit out of my depth in trying to figure out how to correctly structure a table that has 100+ million rows. I know this gets asked a lot, but I haven't found an answer that matches exactly what I'm trying to do.

**The table**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Trades]
(
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [TimeStamp] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [Type] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Amount] [decimal](18, 2) NOT NULL,
    [Price] [decimal](18, 2) NOT NULL,
    [Exchange_Id] [int] NOT NULL
)
```

As you can see, this is a table that stores commodity trades. Because of that, there are currently 100+ million rows in the table, with about 10,000 rows being added daily (at the end of the day).

I'm at a bit of a loss as to how to index this table to maximize performance. I don't so much care about insert performance since the table is updated once a day and it doesn't need to be a fast operation. Rows are also never updated once inserted. The big problem is query speed. This table is queried relatively often.

By far the most common queries are on the `[TimeStamp]` column alone (eg, TimeStamp between two dates), or on the `[TimeStamp]` column together with the `[Exchange_Id]` column (eg, trades on a certain Exchange between two [TimeStamp]s).

Currently, there is a unique clustered index on the `[Id]` column, but I'm not sure if that's the right thing to do based on the circumstances. I've considered making the clustered index on the `[TimeStamp]` column, but it would have to be non-unique which I've read is generally bad. As for non-clustered indexes, I'm not quite sure how to arrange them or on what columns.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you aware that indice work only on high selectivity (low no. of values is returned). Please post queries. Do you know how to read query planner output? There is a great free online book: http://use-the-index-luke.com/ ;)

Comment: @MladenUzelac Thanks for the comment! I'll check out that site. In the meantime, most of the queries involve narrow timespans of several days, so ~40,000 rows returned. There are times, however, where someone may want longer time periods in which case it's easily possible for ~500,000 records to be returned.

Comment: Index will work if there is about 2% percent of data selected. You can always analyize query planner and see what is actually done. Good video about query planner: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lH2_SI04PWQ

Comment: @MladenUzelac Thanks, so that means that indexes should work as long as users query less than 2 million rows on this table, which is always the case. The largest queries I've seen were for ~500k rows.

Comment: It should be. There are many videos about optimization SQL server on Youtube. And you could post some queries so you can get some advice on queries. And `EXPLAIN` is your friend. :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on your question, I would index the `Timestamp` column with the clustered index. And to make the index unique, just make sure to include the identity column in the index definition:

```
... PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Timestamp], [Id])
```

If query performance for queries on `Exchange_Id` is still an issue after that, you can also add a non-clustered index that looks something like this:

```
UNIQUE INDEX ([Exchange_Id], [Timestamp], [Id])
```

.. but if you do, consider including any columns that the query may need, in order to create what's known as a [covering index](http://sqlsunday.com/2013/02/24/covering-indexes/).

```
UNIQUE INDEX ([Exchange_Id], [Timestamp], [Id]) INCLUDE ([Type], [Amount], [Price])
```

Remember that there's a disk space issue involved as well, as you stated that your table contains a large number of rows. The clustered index will not change the amount of disk space your table consumes either way, but adding a non-clustered index *will* allocate extra space. If you `INCLUDE` all the columns from your table, like I did in the example, the non-clustered index will roughly take up as much space as the rest of the table does.

Comment: Thanks so much! This is exactly the kind of information I was hoping to learn. For the PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED index, should the [TimeStamp] and [Id] columns be sorted ASC? Or will the sorting not matter?

Comment: One more question - since we have a fixed number of Exchanges in the system, should I maybe create a new UNIQUE INDEX for each Exchange? In other words, create a UNIQUE INDEX with a WHERE [Exchange_Id] = <Id>? This should improve index speeds further, right?

Comment: Ascending/descending won't matter on Exchange_Id and Timestamp. I would order Id ascending, though.

Comment: Not sure if you would see any large benefits from creating multiple filtered indexes. What you're suggesting is an alternative to partitioning, though. Try it with the non-clustered index if you have the time and an Enterprise Edition license.